# Can ANTLR4 parsers (in Java) be instrumented to be interruptible?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'd like to run my ANTLR parser with an `ExecutorService` so I can call `Future.cancel()` on it after a timeout. AIUI, I need the parser to check `Thread.isInterrupted()`; is there a mechanism in the parser interface for this kind of instrumentation?

In the cases where this is relevant, the parser seems to be deep in `PredictionContext` recursion.

Comment: Fortunately it's open source...

Comment: Not in the public API, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ParseCancellationException (https://javadoc.io/doc/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime/latest/index.html).

Per the docs: “This exception is thrown to cancel a parsing operation. This exception does not extend RecognitionException, allowing it to bypass the standard error recovery mechanisms. BailErrorStrategy throws this exception in response to a parse error.”

You can attach a Listener that overrides enterEveryRule() to your parser.  You could have a method on that listener to set a flag to throw the ParseCancellationException the next time the parser enters a rule (which happens very frequently).

Here's a short example of what the listener might look like:

```java
public class CancelListener extends YourBaseListener {
    public boolean cancel = false;

    @Override
    public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
        if (cancel) {
            throw new ParseCancellationException("gotta go");
        }
        super.enterEveryRule(ctx);
    }
}
```

then you can add that listener to your parser:

```java
 parser.addParseListener(cancelListener);
```

And then:

```java
cancelListener.cancel = true
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, much appreciated. I've done this as a partial fix, but in my case it's the evaluation of a single rule that is degenerate, so it can be minutes between rule entries. I'm looking into optimizing that rule with some of the suggestions in https://tomassetti.me/improving-the-performance-of-an-antlr-parser/